# How to make display resolution 1360 x 768 permanantly?

Tags: intel-graphics, display-resolution

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have to run the commands below every time I switch on the computer.

```
xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00"   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1 1360x768_60.00
```

How can I set the resolution permanently?

Comment: Please give us more information on which graphics card you're using :)

Comment: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphic and Uubntu 16.04

Comment: You could make a `.sh` script, and then use this answer to make it run on boot: https://askubuntu.com/a/923484/698002

Answer (score 1):

1. Run terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type: `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`.
3. Add your script to the file (before `exit` command):

   `xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00"   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync`.

   `xrandr --addmode DP-1 1360x768_60.00`.
4. Save and Exit.
5. Restart.

The script on `/etc/rc.local` is called when your computer starts. So you do not need to type the script every time when your computer boots.

Comment: it does not execute at start up. pls help....

Comment: OK, what is your ubuntu distro and gpu? Have you tried `xrandr --addmode VGA1 1360x768`? Next, please send screenshot of Application->Monitor.

Comment: Don't forget to include dropdown of resolutions. And send the output of `cat /etc/rc.local`

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 , and gpu is Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphic, Your help is highly appreciated.